# Rails Controller - getting the index action to display only certain records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller

By default the rails controller will load all associated objects in the index action.  What I would like to do is display only certain objects.

For example

I have a model called Car(id, make, model, year).  I want list only particular makes in the index, depending on a parameter.

There are a few ways to do this, I'm just not sure which is best.

I could:

pass a parameter to the link:

```
cars_path(make: 'Acura')
```

and would give me /cars/?make=Acura

set up routes: (this seems to get messy)

```
match "cars/:make" => "cars#index", constraints: {make: /[A-z]{1,20}/}
```

or I could make a separate controller action for this

Any suggestion about what is the most "rails-y" way to do this?  RoR 3.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to display the cars of one make, the best url imo would be: `/makes/1-Acura/cars`. So you would just get the cars of this make in the cars controller.

Do you have a table for makes or is it just a string in your car table? I think you should have one.

```
resources :makes do
    resources :cars
end
```

With these routes, you would have to test if there is a params[:make_id] in the index action of the cars controller, and if it's the case you would get the cars like that:

```
@cars = Make.find(params[:make_id]).cars
```

Or you could set up your routes like that

```
resources :makes do
    scope :module => "make_scope" do
        resources :cars
    end
end
```

This way, you can have your controllers setup like that:

```
controllers
    - cars_controller.rb
    - make_scope (folder)
        - cars_controller.rb
```

The path `make_cars_path(@make)` would hit the index action in the make_scope/cars_controller, so you would not have to worry about the presence of a params[:make_id], you would just know you're working with the cars of a make.

Otherwise, the get params are fine. I don't think it's bad to define a new route to get prettier urls though, depending on the complexity of your filters.

Answer (score 3):

Usually, when we are talking of filtering data, I prefer to keep the same index action and filtering parameters via plain old GET vars (no extra route definitions) `url?key=val&key-val`.

This has a number of benefits among them:

- url is bookmark-able
- no session tinkering
- I can reuse the filtering params and pass them to pagination links and such to have the filter follow the user while search is in order

I prefer not to make extra routes as the complexity of the filter can easily go too high. If the filter params are few and you are sure of what you are doing, you may define extra nice routes `url/param/param` but I find that those cases are few to none.